# Validate Foursquare URL for any user in javascript

Tags: jquery-validate, foursquare

Can any one tell me that how validate the Foursquare URL in javascript function.

We had validate the facebbok URL by calling ajax call to graph api. Is there any such api in foursquare.

pls help me for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function ajaxCallToValidateFoursquare(){
    var CLIENT_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
    var CLIENT_SECRET = "xxxxxxxxxx";
    var foursquareUrl="https://foursquare.com/v/mh31-headquarters/4e4d100a52b1075a63924a4a"
    var validFoursquareUrl = "foursquare.com/";
    if($("#foursquareUrl").val()!=null && $("#foursquareUrl").val() != ""){
        if(foursquareUrl.indexOf(validFoursquareUrl) != -1){
            var placeName=foursquareUrl.substring(foursquareUrl.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
            var questionIndex = placeName.indexOf("?");
            if(questionIndex > 0)
                placeName = placeName.substring(0, questionIndex);
            $.getJSON('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/'+placeName+'?client_id='+CLIENT_ID+'&client_secret='+CLIENT_SECRET+'&v='+new Date().format("yyyymmdd"),function(data){
                //get Response in JSON - data
            });

        }

    }
}
```

> here clientid and secretkey are your apps info from foursquare. and Date.format method returns current seconds.

Answer (score 0):

There's no API for foursquare which validates foursquare URLs.